# Google Maps version 3

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-api-2

What's the replacement of getVertexCount() in v3 of google maps? Please let me know. I am using the same in my code for v3, but it doesn't seem to be working. Is there any replacement for getVertexCount() in v3 or there's no mandatory replacement? Please let me know the replacement function if there is. I am providing the initialize() function of my version2 code. Please suggest. Following is the initialize function of my version 2 code :

```
function initialize() {
            if (GBrowserIsCompatible()) {

                // Initialize geocoder for address search
                geocoder = new GClientGeocoder();

                // Draw the map
                var startPoint = parseCoordinate(VALUE_SITE_COORDINATE);
                map = new GMap2(document.getElementById(ID_DIV_MAP_CANVAS));
                map.setCenter(startPoint, 13);
                map.setUIToDefault();

                // Listener for map mouse move event showing pointer coordinates
                GEvent.addListener(map, 'mousemove', function(latlng) {
                    document.getElementById(ID_INPUT_CURRENT_COORDINATE).value = latlng;
                });

                // Draw the main polygon
                var coordinates = parseCoordinates(VALUE_COORDINATES);
                if( coordinates.length  > 0)
                {
                    polygon = createPolygonOnInit(coordinates);
                    map.addOverlay(polygon);
                    if (polygon.getVertexCount() == MAX_VERTICES_RECTANGLE) {
                        createBackgroundPolygon();
                    }

                    adjustMapAppearance(map);
                }


                // Render polygon coordinates
                showCoordinates(coordinates);

                // Create our "tiny" marker icon
                var blueIcon = new GIcon(G_DEFAULT_ICON);
                blueIcon.image = "http://www.google.com/intl/en_us/mapfiles/ms/micons/blue-dot.png";

                // Set up our GMarkerOptions object
                markerOptions = { icon:blueIcon };
                map.addOverlay(new GMarker(startPoint, markerOptions));

                // Set initial state
                if (coordinates.length == 0) {
                    setState(STATE_NO_GEO_FENCE);
                } else {
                    setState(STATE_READ_GEO_FENCE);
                    prevstate = STATE_READ_GEO_FENCE;
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: What do you need to do?  What does your v3 code look like?  I think you could use `getLength()`, see https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#MVCArray  ... but it'd help to know a bit more

Comment: I need to convert my code from google maps version2 to google maps version3.

Comment: ... so add your version2 code here for starters

Comment: I am providing the initialize() function of my version2 code. please suggest.

Comment: it'd also help to see the `createPolygonOnInit` function I think

Answer (score 0):

So...

- you have an array of coordinates,
- you create a polygon
- if the polygon has 4 vertices, you create your background polygon

Assuming you've managed to rewrite all the rest of your code to v3 (and if so, it'd help to also add that to your question), and you just need to work out this last bit for checking the vertices), you could try:

```js
path = polygon.getPath();
if (path.getLength() == MAX_VERTICES_RECTANGLE) {
```